# Sand box environment for Data Lake Store and Analytics

Tags: azure-data-lake

Is there any sand box environment for Data Lake Store and Analytics so that I don't have to use my Azure Credits?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) does have a mode for local execution.  You install an emulator and this enables you to run your U-SQL scripts from Visual Studio either against your local instance or your Azure ADLA account.

Some reading on the topic:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/run-u-sql-scripts-locally-with-updated-azure-data-lake-tools-for-visual-studio/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-sdk

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ADL tool with VisualStudio Community Edition which gives you the experience for free.